# Is there any mechanism to obtain location data for a web application running on an Android Device without enabling device location settings

Tags: android, html, web, geolocation

I want to obtain the location of users' for a web application without wanting them to externally enable the location via the Android device location settings.

Currently I'm using HTML5 Geolocation API to obtain the users' location. The problem is when the web page is viewed through an Android Device, other than enabling the location permissions on the browser, Android device built in location settings should also be enabled to obtain the location.

I want to find out whether there is a mechanism where you can achieve this kind of a thing. Though I did spend lot of time searching through the internet for a tip, couldn't find a one. Glad if any one could give an idea about my approach here.

Comment: you can use IP lookup to get the coordinates for IP address of the client. It is not accurate, but fortunately there is no better way. It would be a great security issue if web site could get your location if you denied it.

Comment: Thanks for the response!, but according to my knowledge if a user deny to share their location within the browser there won't be any issue. Because geolocation api won't share the location after that with the website. But the problem is even when the user has allowed to share the location from the browser level, they should separately make sure that android device location settings are turned on.